# Wall takes up lighting only in specific camera angles

Tags: shadows

In my blender file I have a problem with the the way the wall catches the shadow/light. In previous renders this worked completely fine
[previous render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzgQL.jpg),
but when I switched to blender 3.0 the lighting seemed to change.
Here a short video on how the light changes with the angle of view.
[showcase of changing shadow](https://i.imgur.com/mMokAXw.mp4)
Here is the [material shader node setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfyta.png), the [render passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfVKT.png) and the [seetings for the main lightsource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0FiV.png).

Thank you very much, I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use the [built in tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)
to add images to your question. Use an image editor, or online 
optimizer, if you must resize an image. You    
can help those who would answer your question if all the information 
is displayed as part of the question and not as links.

Comment: This is really strange, at least from what I can tell looking at the video. It seems like something is moving together with the view and obstructs the light. You can also see it over the stairs in the background, the previous render had the light fall in from the top while in the video it is shadowed...

Answer (score -1):

[image: lighting settings]

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but the light itself also has a shadow setting that often times people aren't aware of called "shadow" and "contact shadow" make sure both of them are on. Then try adjusting the contact shadow "distance" amount and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes I thought so too. But the only settings available for the light source are the ones shown under the previous post "settings for the main light source". Even if I change it to a point or spot light, the settings stay exactly the same. Maybe it is a change in 3.0 that I am not aware of, that moved those settings to another place.

Comment: @metacontent The _Shadow_ options like _Contact Shadows_ are only available in _Eevee_.  Although not stated in the question, the short video looks like he's using _Cycles_.

Comment: Yes I am sorry for not having menshioned that, but you are right. This is cycles